# How can i click submit button

Tags: selenium, xpath, submit, form-submit, submit-button

How can i click on submit button on the given html

```
<span class="sbt-btn-wrap relative">
<input class="submit icon" type="submit" onclick="submitmnLogin($(this), 'testPrepLogin');trackGaEvent('Content Hub Home','Login Popup','Login Button');">
```

I have tried

```
driver.findElement(By.className("sbt-btn-wrap relative")).click();
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.className("submit icon")).click();
```

but it is not working.

Comment: **Stackoverflow** is a community for the programmers by the programmers, please visit its [**How to Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section before posting any question, as it will help you as well as other SOusers too.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay - well, I think the click *was* to be performed programmatically (see "I have tried...")

Comment: @0X0nosugar vivek's point is that this is a really, really basic question. The OP should be able to look at the error messages, google them, and find answers to questions like this for him/herself.

Comment: @JeffC - ok. I had this question on the review queue and you can see that I'm not on SO for long. It's sometimes difficult to tell what a person can easily find out, and the 'help section' expressly mentions the possibility of people asking for homework help *if* they "include a summary of the work" they've done. Having said that, I meant to be nice to the OP and certainly had no intention of being overly critical of anybody else. And I'm sorry if anybody got another impression.

Comment: @0X0nosugar you are correct and I didn't take your comment as critical. I was merely trying to point out that even though someone follows the rules as far as good formatting, there are some questions that should not be asked. Part of [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is doing your own research. If the OP did their homework and googled their own question, they would have found the answer. IF they found an answer but didn't understand it, that would be a more appropriate question but even those questions have most likely been asked and answered.

Comment: To the OP... "it is not working." is not very clear. What was the result? Did you try anything other than className()? What was the result? Spend a few minutes reading/googling and learn more about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 9):

When you have two class names with space separating them, then you cannot use `By.className` on it. Instead use `By.cssSelector` to click on the element. Here's how -

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".submit.icon")).click();
```

If you still want to use className then use one class name that is unique to the element and click on it -

```
driver.findElement(By.className("submit")).click();
```

You can use other attributes to click the input element. I prefer using cssSelector instead of xpath as its slow -

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='submit']")).click();
```

Here's an example of xpath too -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();
```

If you are not able to find submit button element in a unique way then use other unique element to find input element.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sbt-btn-wrap relative .submit")).click();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Aren't you missing some escaping in the xpath?

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of way's using this HTML code for the button

```
<input type="button" id="btn_submit" class="some_class" value="Submit">
```

And use the following jquery code (you must include jquery on you page!)

```
$('#btn_submit').click(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Or performing the same still using jquery, but handle the click with the class and not by ID (recommended only if you want to handle the same on multiple elements)

```
$('.some_class').click(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Now with javascript by ID no need to include the jquery library

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("btn_submit").click(); // Click on the checkbox
}
```

And by css

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".some class)).click();
```

Hope this is what you want and this helps you.
Check the first comment on your question too

Comment: Thanks Girish and Pedro

Comment: If it's working mark as answered to help other members of the community.

Answer (score 0):

replace `.click()` with `.submit()` and it may work. You could be working with an HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by help of CSSSelector using of List web element

```
String cssSelectorOfButton="input[type='button'][id='login']"; 
//****Add cssSelector of your button webelement
List<WebElement> loginButton 
=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(cssSelectorOfButton));
loginButton.get(0).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[type=submit]').click()
```

try this, it worked for me