# Selenium: submit() works fine, but click() does not

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I have submit button, which is only one on the page, and it's in form.

html part:

```
<form class="search-form ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid" novalidate="" style="" xpath="1">

<div class="row">...</div>
<div class="row">...</div>
<div class="row">...</div>
<div class="form__actions" xpath="1">
    <div class="form__buttons">
      <!---->
      <div class="btn__wrapper">
        <button class="btn btn__primary" type="submit">
          Select My Car
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

So, I'm taking xpath:

```
//button[@type='submit']
```

I'm successfully pressing it via submit() (let me skip WebDriver init, its fine):

```
  WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']"));
  searchButton.submit();
```

(and some search performs)

But when I'm trying to press it via click()

```
WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']"));
        searchButton.click();
```

it's not pressed in browser which is launched, and same time Junit test is green (not test, but just pressing button):

```
@Test
    public void test() {
        WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']"));
        button.click();
    }
```

Can please someone explain, why submit() successfully presses button in such case, but click() - no. And I do not understand, why "test" is green, when we are trying to click(), but it was not performed, if looking on browser launched by driver.

**UPDATED:**
I tried

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']"));
        if (button.isEnabled()) {
            button.click();
        }
```

and

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(button)).click();
```

but still the same - submit() works fine, click() - does not.

Comment: I am not sure how it is used, but from the documentation click doesn't wait for next page load, whereas submit will wait for the action to complete. Could this be the reason ?

Comment: Can you update the question with relevant HTML please?

Comment: I added till 2 divs higher, please note, will it be enough

Comment: @gvmani: sounds reasonable, thanks... let's wait for some more explanations.

Comment: Is the button in a form? If so, please show the form element.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: sure. added.

Comment: The `form` does not appear to have an `action`.

Comment: so, click works only when forms has an action, and submit does not need it(action) ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at some similar posts:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530104/selenium-webdriver-submit-vs-click https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32779563/how-can-i-click-submit-button

Answer (score 5):

The method `object.submit()` is there for submitting the form to the server. It has another advantage, in case if you're not able to locate the "submit" button then you can take any object of the form and trigger submit() function. 
It seems in `searchButton.submit();` searchButton is an element of the form and the submit action on it triggers submission of form on server.

Now, why `searchButton.click();` not working here could have following reasons.

1. The button is visible but not enabled.
2. Driver is finding the 2
   instances of `searchButton` element.

Suggestion: Evaluate following code and check it returns more than one element. If it does then you're clicking on the wrong instance.

```
List<WebElements> e = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']"));
```

Also try,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@class='btn btn__primary'][@type='submit']")).click()
```

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#user-input-filling-in-forms

Comment: 1) e.size = 1. 2) I tried proposed click() - but the same - button not pressed in browser launched.  Thanks for pointing me to check visibility/enableness, I will play with it.

Comment: You should try for element being enabled instead of visible. Also, could you tell me which browser you're using?

Comment: I ment "enabled" ofc, sorry, mistype. Browser - Firefox 57.02

Comment: Can you try following code: WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
            .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
                    .id("//button[@type='submit']")));
element.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN); AND JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Comment: it works, man). but the question was about directly click() command. I can use just submit(), which works without JS calling. let me play with e.g. isEnabled

Comment: Your application seems to be an Angular one. This post can help you in building the understanding. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499174/selenium-click-event-does-not-trigger-angularjs-ng-click

Comment: I voted it up, as it helped me to understand JS usage a bit (I guess it will be good e.g. when scrolling needed), but I can't accept it as final answer:). I really confused, why click() seems to be work badly. Ofc, I can just forget this, and use submit() or JS further, but I prefer to find knowledge.

Comment: You said you're trying it on Firefox, could you try the click() on Chrome? Also, when you click on the button is it visible to your eyes? I mean do you need to scroll down to it?

Answer (score 1):

### **`submit()`**

[**`submit()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#submit--) method is defined as :

```
void submit()

Throws:
NoSuchElementException - If the given element is not within a form
```

As per the [JavaDocs](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#submit--) when you invoke **`submit()`** on an `WebElement`, if this current element is a form, or an element within a form, then this will be submitted to the remote server. If this causes the current page to change, then this method will block until the new page is loaded.

### **`click()`**

[**`click()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#click--) method is defined as :

```
void click()

Throws:
StaleElementReferenceException - If the element no longer exists as initially define
```

As per the [JavaDocs](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#click--) when you invoke **`click()`** on an `WebElement` and if this causes a new page to load, you should discard all references to this element and any further operations performed on this element will throw a StaleElementReferenceException. Note that if click() is done by sending a native event (which is the default on most browsers/platforms) then the method will *not* wait for the next page to load and the caller should verify that themselves. There are some **ExpectedConditions** for an element to be clicked. The element must be **visible** and it must have a `height` and `width` **greater then 0**.

---

### Your Usecase :

In your usecase, the target `WebElement` **`//button[@type='submit']`** is within a **`<form>`** tag. You are able to successfully press it via **`submit()`** as it blocks the method untill the new page is loaded completely as a result of submission on the previous page. Hence the following works :

```
WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']"));
searchButton.submit();
```

But when you try **`click()`** method as below, `click()` being a native event doesn't waits for the new page to load completely. Hence invoking `click()` method fails.

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']"));
button.click();
```

### Your Code Trials :

Validating the **`button.isEnabled()`** condition won't fetch us the required result if the element is clickable or not as [**`isEnabled()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isEnabled--) validates `Is the element currently enabled or not? This will generally return true for everything leaving out the disabled input elements`. But necessarily **`isEnabled()`** wouldn't be validating if the `WebElement` is **visible**, **interactable** and **clickable** or not.

---

### Solution :

As per the details provided, the solution to invoke **`click()`** method would be to induce **`WebDriverWait`** with `ExpectedConditions` clause set to [**`elementToBeClickable`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) as below :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']"))).click();
```

---

### Update :

### Best Practice :

As per the updated `HTML` and your subsequent comment where you mentioned about `Angular4` being used in your app, a much more effective way would be to construct the `xpath` mocking the `HTML DOM` as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//form[@class='search-form ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid']//button[@class='btn btn__primary' and @type='submit']"))).click();
```

Comment: I already tried this (see section "Updated" in question), and it does not work. Some of comments led me to read about Angular~Selenium friendship, so I will proceed with that nearest days.  (yep, Angular4 used in my app).

Comment: Did you get a chance to go through my updated Answer? Let me know the status please.

Comment: I'm bit overload by main work, will try in working order, thanks.

Comment: no, still same behaviour (test "green", but no action after click()). I checked Xpath/element presence on the page.