# UnsupportedOperationError: sendKeysToActiveElement error while invoking sendKeys(Key.ENTER) with Protractor and Internet Explorer 11

Tags: selenium, webdriver, protractor, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver

The environment I'm using is

- Protractor 5.3.1
- Cucumber 4.2.1
- IE11
- selenium-webdriver 3.6.0

On the page in the application I am testing there is no button to click on, you need to enter text into an input field then send the ENTER key. The following works fine in chrome and firefox.

```
browser.driver.findElement(By.className('myClass')).then((text) => {
    text.sendKeys('abc'); // this works fine in IE11
    text.sendKeys(Key.ENTER);
});
```

The issue is that it won't send the ENTER key in IE11, it just skips over this step and fails on the next step in the test.

I also tried this:

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.RETURN).perform();
```

When I tried this the following error is returned:

```
[15:29:10] E/launcher - UnsupportedOperationError: sendKeysToActiveElement
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
System info: host: 'ABC', ip: '9.162.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that the following line doesn't works:

```
text.sendKeys(Key.ENTER);
```

As an alternative you can use:

```
text.sendKeys(Key.RETURN);
```

You can find a detailed discussion in [Typing Enter/Return key in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629053/typing-enter-return-key-in-selenium/47830036#47830036)

Incase the element is within a **form** you can also use another alternative as:

```
text.submit();
```

You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium: submit() works fine, but click() does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47992533/selenium-submit-works-fine-but-click-does-not)

Additionally, while you work with *Internet Explorer v11* you need to configure your *test framework* with the [Required Configuration](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver). Apart from these specifically ***only for IE 11*** you will need to set a *registry entry* on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of *Internet Explorer* it creates as follows:

- For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is:

  ```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE.
  ```
- For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is:

  ```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE.
  ```

You can find a detailed discussion in [Internet Explorer 11 getting stuck randomly while executing tests through IEDriverServer and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977120/internet-explorer-11-getting-stuck-randomly-while-executing-tests-through-iedriv/51983888#51983888)

Comment: I tried 'text.sendKeys(Key.RETURN)' but it didn't work. I read the discussion 'Typing Enter/Returnkey in Selenium' and tried some of the suggestions in it but still can't get it work.

My element is not within a form so that doesn't work either.

I think its related to IE11, as like I said it works fine in chrome and firefox

Comment: @AutoTester Checkout my updated answer and let me know the result.

Comment: I already had added that property into my registry so that's not the issue

Comment: Did you take some time to cross check the related discussion I have provided for your reference and the links within that discussion?

Comment: Yes, I read the other discussions you mentioned and changed some capabilities settings as suggested but none made a difference