# How to click on the element with text as LOGIN as per the website through Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

Windows 10Home x64 /
Python 3.7.0 win64 /
Selenium 3.14.0 /
Geckodriver 3.14.0 /
Firefox 61.0.2.

I'm trying to click on the login button, even though I have copied and pasted the full XPath I am not able to click the Login button.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://library.yonsei.ac.kr/')
linkElem = driver.find_element_by_link_text('LOGIN').click() 
username = driver.find_element_by_id('id')
username.send_keys('myuserAbc')
password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
password.send_keys('mypass123')
linkElem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/fieldset/div[2]/p[@class='loginBtn']/input[@type='submit']").click()
```

Thank you for your help.

Update1: The script works up to the point of localizing the login button, I don't have problems with Marionette or having the latest Firefox version.

Update2: I added `p[@class='loginBtn']/input[@type='submit']` in an effort to make it more specific but still doesn't work.

Comment: Try `password.submit()` instead of clicking Submit button

Comment: Hi Andersson, when i run that command it takes me back to the previous page (http://library.yonsei.ac.kr/) 
any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience i have found that the button click might not work some times on form buttons with type  set to action. The best possible way to work through this one will be to use the submit() method.

so something like this should work on your login form

```
from time import sleep
time.sleep(20) 
driver.find_element_by_class_name('loginBtn').submit()
```

This will submit the form to the server and you will be able to go through the login process.

if that doesn't work you could also try the follwoing

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('loginBtn).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

> Now, why Button.click(); not working here could have following
>   reasons.
>
> 1.The button is visible but not enabled.
>
> 2.Driver is finding the 2 instances of Button element
>
> .More discussion about this can be found here
>   [Selenium: submit() works fine, but click() does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47992533/selenium-submit-works-fine-but-click-does-not)

Comment: Hi Jishnu, i tried the first command 
   self.driver.click_element_by_class_name('loginBtn').submit()  but got this error "self.driver.click_element_by_class_name('loginBtn').submit()
NameError: name 'self' is not defined" how should I define self?

Comment: Hi Jishnu, i tried the first command 
   self.driver.click_element_by_class_name('loginBtn').submit()  
but got this error "self.driver.click_element_by_class_name('loginBtn').submit()
NameError: name 'self' is not defined" how should I define self?

Also tried this:
linkElem = driver.click_element_by_class_name('loginBtn').submit()

but got the following error:
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'click_element_by_class_name'

Comment: self is the reference to the current instance of a class.  i see that you are not defining any classes. I have made a type in the answer. It has been updated and should work now

Comment: Let me know if it works or if it is still giving you exceptions

Comment: couldn't log in.

Comment: What exception are you getting ?

Comment: I couldn't log in. Got this error:

    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <li class="loginBtn"> is not reachable by keyboard

Comment: Is this the case with both submit() and send_keys() method ?

Comment: with submit() i got this error:
 (...) line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: ./ancestor-or-self::form

Comment: i changed it to:
    import time
    time.sleep(20) 
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('loginBtn').submit()
but got this error:

    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: ./ancestor-or-self::form

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared to invoke `click()` on the element with text as **LOGIN** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title='Login']>span"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Login']/span"))).click()
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: thank you for the try, i run the script but it doesn't log in.  I think there must be something in the website preventing automatic login.

Comment: @AndresToro What exactly do you mean by `for the try`? Code is well tested and working. Where are you stuck? Update the question with your current code attempt and error stack trace for further analysis.

Comment: please check edit comments.  I'm learning Python and I can't tell you why is not working, but I can show you what does it return after running it.

Comment: @AndresToro See the initial version of your question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52013464/1). Your question was pretty mush specific as it read _Im trying to click on the login button_ and _I am not able to click Login button_. But now after receiving well researched answers you are modifying your question on each and every edit which is _unethical_ as per stackoverflow standards. In case your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement. For this time I am reverting back the question to it's initial version.

Comment: I will post a new more specific questions as you suggested.  Thank you.